# z-index problem in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, z-index

I have been struggling with a z-index problem in IE6 for quite some time now. I require part of the 'header' portion in my website to open up (using jQuery), and cover a portion of the 'content' section which comes after it. The thing works like a charm on all the browsers I've tested it on (Firefox, Chrome, Opera), but IE6 instead pushes down the content section, which is not what I want.

The website itself is [here](http://simonkagwe.com)

I have done extensive research both here on SO and thro Google but all the workarounds I've found don't work for my case. Please help.

Comment: if it pushes the content down then it is not a `z-index` issue but a positioning issue..

Answer (score 0):

hi add this code specially for IE6 in class

```
    .imageflow .scrollbar {
    border-bottom:1px solid #b3b3b3;
    position:relative; 
    visibility:hidden;
    z-index:10002;
    _z-index:10002;
    _top:-10px;
    height:1px;
}
```

Comment: which class? the one i want to be on top (header)? what's with the underscores?

Comment: underscores is attack only IE6. this use only for IE6.scrollbar come to top by _top.

Comment: Thanks Rajput. It solves the issue with my scrollbar, but still I'm not getting the desired effect with my header when I click on the "Read more about me" link. Any ideas?